# ImportError: /home/u8400/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cblas_dtrs

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, dlib

[Dlib import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPeQB.png)

I was trying to use **dlib** for face landmark estimation on. I got this error. Can someone please provide a solution.

Python3.6

PS: I am using [Colfax Hub](https://hub.colfaxresearch.com). So I do not have root access